# Serve static images/files from NodeJS URL localhost to VueJS

Tags: node.js

What is the correct code format to establish the static server from nodejs

This is my current code to declare the static server and won't work

```
app.use(express.static( './src/uploads'));
```

My URL that used to be fetch by Vuejs from nodejs folder

http://localhost:5000/src/uploads/100-cities-with-the-most-beautiful-women-in-the-world.jpg

As you can see on the image this is the folder structure

```
-ecommerce-backend

 -src

  -uploads
```

[image: As you can]

Comment: Did you tried this url `http://localhost:5000/100-cities-with-the-most-beautiful-women-in-the-world.jpg`

Comment: yes and it says Cannot GET

Comment: where is your main file `app.js` located inside `src` folder or outside? If it's inside path must be wrong.

Comment: it is located outside the src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working code used in one of my projects is

```
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

You can replace `public` with your dir name. The directory structure for the project is

```
-routes
-models
-public
app.js
```

Nodejs version is

```
node -v
v10.16.0
```

Comment: Like this?
localhost:5000/public/100-cities-with-the-most-beautiful-women-in-the-world.jpg

Comment: No need to include the `public` in the path. `localhost:5000/myfile.jpg`

Comment: Sir, salute to you, been trying to solve this problem since yesterday. thanks a lot